# Using handler with p:hotkey and p:commandButton in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, hotkeys

Well, i have a commandButton like this:

```
   <p:commandButton value="Novo" id="commandButtonCadastrar" widgetVar="varCommandButtonNovo" oncomplete="varDialogManterEndereco.show()" actionListener="#{enderecoMB.novo}" />
```

And i have a hotkey to simulate the button clicks, like this:

```
  <p:hotkey bind="alt+n" handler="varCommandButtonNovo.click()" />
```

But when i use "alt+n" in browser nothing happens.

Answer (score 4):

You can access jQuery Methods like `click` over the `jq` attribute on most Primefaces components. If you change your code like this

```xml
<p:hotkey bind="alt+n" handler="varCommandButtonNovo.jq.click()" />
```

It should work.

Comment: In newer Primefaces versions, one should get the widget using: PF('varCommandButtonNovo').jq.click()

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="remotecommand" process="@this"
                 action="#{mbname.method()}"
                 rendered="#{.......}"
                 update=":messageForm:growl" />             
<script type="text/javascript">
  //For Ctrl+Shift+F1
  $(window).keydown(function(event) {
    if(event.ctrlKey &amp;&amp; event.shiftKey &amp;&amp; event.keyCode == 112) { 
      remotecommand();
      event.preventDefault(); 
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't depend on the *p:commandButton*. Just duplicate the AJAX-logic in *p:hotkey*:

```
<p:hotkey bind="alt+n" actionListener="#{enderecoMB.novo}" oncomplete="varDialogManterEndereco.show()" />
```